# Get a new Sql id after submition by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After submission a comment of a post with ajax, comment.php display new comment with its own SQL auto increment id. like:

```
// Here $id comes from SQL after submit data
<div class="comment'.$id.'"><ul>

// new comment

</ul></div>
```

Now, how to get this new id in Ajax complete: function(data) from comment.php to show it post.php page into .

I tried this code which not working:

```
complete: function(data){
var ID = $(this).attr('id').replace('comment','');
$(".comment"+ID).append(data.responseText);
$(".comment"+ID).fadeIn(2000);
}
```

complete code:

```
$(".repfrm").click(function(){
error.fadeOut();
if(checkForm()){
var author = inputAuthor.attr("value");
var url = inputUrl.attr("value");
var img = inputImg.attr("value");
var replycom = inputReplycom.attr("value");
var parent_id = inputparent_id.attr("value");
var tutid = inputTutid.attr("value");

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "comment.php", data: "action=insert&author="+ author + "&replycom="+ replycom + "&url="+ url + "&img="+ img + "&parent_id="+ parent_id + "&tutid="+ tutid,

            complete: function(data){
error.fadeOut();
var ID = $(this).attr('id').replace('comment','');
$(".comment"+ID).append(data.responseText);
$(".comment"+ID).fadeIn(2000);                          


}); 
}
});
    }
    else //alert("Please fill all fields!");
error_message();
});
```

Comment: Hi, do you get the Id from the comment.php in your Ajax callback?

Comment: I want to get the id from comment.php in your Ajax callback. But its not work sir.

Comment: Is it possible like this $(".reply"{UnknownId}).append(data.responseText);

Comment: I have downvoted you because you haven't specified what error you're getting or what happens when it doesn't work, just that it's not working.  Please clarify the issue.  Are you getting errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I am still working now. And can get any good result. Thank you.

Comment: Colin vH, I have no error. I just want to do it if possible. And my question already clear above (Now, how to get this new id in Ajax complete: function(data) from comment.php to show it post.php page)

Answer (score 0):

It helps to describe exactly how your code isn't working, but I think I found it:

```
var ID = $(this).attr('id').replace('comment','');
```

should be

```
var ID = $(this).attr('class').replace('comment','');
```

Answer (score 0):

your attribute is not `id` it is `class` so use something like this:

```
   var ID = $(this).attr('class').replace('comment','');
    $(".comment"+ID).append(data.responseText);
    $(".comment"+ID).fadeIn(2000);
```

see this for sample:

```
<script> 


$( document ).ready(function() {
    var ID = $('div').attr('class').replace('comment','');
    alert(ID);
    });


</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="comment1"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @koch see this a small demo:

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need this:

This is used to get the last insert id, [ID of last record inserted](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Send this into your ajax call back and append as the ID.

Let us know if you want to know how to send this from comment.php